# how to maintain wcf service per session calling url from android studio

Tags: c#, android, wcf, wcf-sessions

I created WCF service and calling it from the android studio and its working fine, but after implementing WCF perSession functionality it is working for a single user at a time.
Problem:
My problem is when i am hitting WCF url with multiple user my sessionID get overwrite by the latest logged in user, So how to maintain session for multiple user like we do in web application.
I used this to creste session in WCF:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerSession)]
```

and this is my method to create sessionid within services class

```
public class MyService : IMyService
{
  static string currentSessionID = string.Empty;

    public string createSession()
    {
        currentSessionID = DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString();
        return currentSessionID;
    }
    public string Login()
    {
        var mysessionId = createSession();
        return mysessionId;
    }
    public string Mymethods(string data)
    {
        string response = "";
        if(data.StartsWith("01"))
           response = Login();
        return response;
    }
}
```

and am hitting this createSession() method only in login function.

Please help me out of this.....
Thanks in advnance.

Comment: You will need a more advanced method of storing sessions. I'm thinking that you should be able to find a library that does this already - perhaps even an official one.

Comment: please help me with some links, coz I didn't find any, and my wcf service is created in visual studio 2010 version.